# Crystal Reports XI - syntax error in query working ok in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a query, and in SQL Server Management Studio (2008), it is working perfectly, but when I add a subreport to my report when the same query with dynamic params, I get two errors.

The first time the values that I set in the set default values like, for example 'A' is interpreted like a column name and showing

> Invalid column name A

When I send a constant 'A' without parameter, no errors are shown.

This is my code:

```
select top 1 
    isnull( dtssegcabv.dscv_fecharecepcion, 0) as FechaRecepcion
from 
    CabVenta 
join 
    dtssegcabv on CabVenta.cvescv_id = dtssegcabv.scv_id
where 
    CabVenta.cve_letra = {?cve_letra} 
    and CabVenta.cve_codpvt = {?cve_codpvt} 
    and CabVenta.cve_nro = {?cve_nro} 
    and CabVenta.cvetco_cod = {?cvetco_cod}
```

If I send no default values (let the dialog empty), the error is

> Incorrect Syntax Near Keyword And

I repeat, the query in SQL Server is working fine. The datatypes are all `varchar`.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a quotes problem:

```
select top 1 
    isnull( dtssegcabv.dscv_fecharecepcion, 0) as FechaRecepcion
from 
    CabVenta 
join 
    dtssegcabv on CabVenta.cvescv_id = dtssegcabv.scv_id
where 
    CabVenta.cve_letra = '{?cve_letra}'
    and CabVenta.cve_codpvt = '{?cve_codpvt}' 
    and CabVenta.cve_nro = '{?cve_nro}' 
    and CabVenta.cvetco_cod = '{?cvetco_cod}'
```

Works Perfectly